# How to convert Google Apps script blob to a base64 encoded string?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an blob within Google Apps Script. How can I convert it to an base64 encoded string in order to write it to other APIs? FileReader seems not to work ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
```

[Ref docs here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(Byte)).

Comment: Thank you, did not found it before!

Answer (score 0):

```
const convertImageToDataUri = () => {
  const imageUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/6rl9Atu.png';
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
  const base64String = Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
  return `data:image/png;base64,${base64String}`;
};
```